# AWS CloudFormation‎ Template : Subnet addresses validation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I have VPC addresses and Subnet addresses as parameters to my template :

```
{
   "Parameters":{
      "VPCAddresses":{
         "Type":"String",
         "MinLength":"9",
         "MaxLength":"18",
         "Default":"10.0.0.0/16",
         "AllowedPattern":"(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})/(\\d{1,2})",
         "ConstraintDescription":"must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x."
      },
      "SubnetAddresses":{
         "Type":"String",
         "MinLength":"9",
         "MaxLength":"18",
         "Default":"10.0.0.0/24",
         "AllowedPattern":"(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})/(\\d{1,2})",
         "ConstraintDescription":"must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x."
      }
   }
}
```

It is possible to validate that the VPC Addresses contain the Subnet Addresses, Before executing the template? Maybe using `Rules`?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment (Jan 2018) I don't believe there is any option using just CFN alone. CFN is a template language that doesn't support these types of operations.

You would have to use another tool like [cfndsl](https://github.com/cfndsl/cfndsl) or [Troposphere](https://github.com/cloudtools/troposphere) that would generate the CFN for you. You would have to write and execute the validation logic before the templates are generated.

Comment: Do you have an example of how to "execute the validation logic before the templates are generated" ?